# Mathematical Rube Goldberg problem

Tags: problem-solving

Is there a book or website that has mathematical rube goldberg-style puzzles? In other words, puzzles that require you to compute something, then compute something based on that, and then iterate for a large number of steps. These puzzles should preferably require undergraduate mathematics from a variety of fields of math.

Comment: I find the phrase "preferably require undergraduate mathematics from a variety of fields of math" amusing.